# How to have video faded when paused - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am just learning web design, and right now I am working on embedding a video with the requirements:

- Initially faded(darkened).
- On mouse hover unfade/brighten to normal.
- When video is being played, do not fade.

Hopefully that makes sense. I have the first two parts working fine, however when I can't figure out how I avoid have it being darkened when its playing.

A chunk of my HTML is:

```
<div class="paused"> 
    <video class="video" id="video1" width="720" onclick="playPause(0)" loop>
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div> 
<script> 
    var videos = [document.getElementById("video1"), document.getElementById("video2")];

    function playPause(num) {
        if (videos[num].paused) {
            videos[num].play(); }
        else {
            videos[num].pause(); }
    }
```

and my CSS is:

```
div.paused {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}

div.paused video {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.4;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
     transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

div.paused:hover video {
    opacity: 1;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the "paused" class on your containing div.  You can do this at the end of your `playPause` function with this:

```
videos[num].parentElement.classList.toggle('paused');
```

That's native DOM with only newer browser support (for [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)); you could do the same thing in jQuery like:

```
$(videos[num]).parent().toggleClass('paused');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) for video. Basically, you listen to different events tied to the video, so in your case you could do something like.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("play", function() { 
    document.querySelector(".paused").removeAttribute('class');
}, true);
```

So when the video starts playing, it will remove the class, you can then add another listener for `pause` to add the class back on. I encourage you to check out the MDN page, as there are a bunch of different ways to interact with it.

Comment: `var v` is just copied from the mdn article. If you have more than one you can do `document.querySelectorAll('video')` and work with them however you want. you would have to attach the event listener to each video.